# Optimizing NGINX + PHP-FPM + MariaDB for WordPress (10k hits/day)?

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, nginx, mariadb

I'm trying to optimize a VPN server that's running Nginx + PHP-FPM + MariaDB for a website that has a lot of traffic.

Machine specs are:

- 8GB RAM
- 8 CPU cores
- 1x30GB SSD

Machine uses CENTOS 7.1

Here's my `nginx.conf`:

```
# Server globals
user                    nginx;
worker_processes        8;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;


# Worker config
events {
        worker_connections  1024;
        use                 epoll;
}


http {
    # Main settings
    sendfile                        on;
    tcp_nopush                      on;
    tcp_nodelay                     on;
    client_header_timeout           1m;
    client_body_timeout             1m;
    client_header_buffer_size       2k;
    client_body_buffer_size         256k;
    client_max_body_size            256m;
    large_client_header_buffers     4   8k;
    send_timeout                    30;
    keepalive_timeout               60 60;
    reset_timedout_connection       on;
    server_tokens                   off;
    server_name_in_redirect         off;
    server_names_hash_max_size      512;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size   512;


    # Log format
    log_format  main    '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $request '
                        '"$status" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    log_format  bytes   '$body_bytes_sent';
    #access_log          /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    access_log off;


    # Mime settings
    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;


    # Compression
    gzip                on;
    gzip_comp_level     9;
    gzip_min_length     512;
    gzip_buffers        8 64k;
    gzip_types          text/plain text/css text/javascript
                        application/x-javascript application/javascript;
    gzip_proxied        any;


    # Proxy settings
    proxy_redirect      off;
    proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass_header   Set-Cookie;
    proxy_connect_timeout   90;
    proxy_send_timeout  90;
    proxy_read_timeout  90;
    proxy_buffers       32 4k;


    # SSL PCI Compliance
    ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers        "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";


    # Error pages
    error_page          403          /error/403.html;
    error_page          404          /error/404.html;
    error_page          502 503 504  /error/50x.html;


    # Cache
    proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=2 keys_zone=cache:10m inactive=60m max_size=512m;
    proxy_temp_path  /var/cache/nginx/temp;
    proxy_cache_key "$host$request_uri $cookie_user";
    proxy_ignore_headers Expires Cache-Control;
    proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_502;
    proxy_cache_valid any 3d;

    map $http_cookie $no_cache {
        default 0;
        ~SESS 1;
        ~wordpress_logged_in 1;
    }


    # Wildcard include
    include             /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Also here's my `domainname.conf`:

```
[domainname.tld]
listen = 127.0.0.1:9003
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1

user = admin
group = admin

pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 70
pm.start_servers = 3
pm.min_spare_servers = 3
pm.max_spare_servers = 10

env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME
env[PATH] = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
env[TMP] = /tmp
env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
env[TEMP] = /tmp
```

And here's the main `www.conf`:

```
[www]
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
user = apache
group = apache
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 3
pm.max_spare_servers = 35
```

And finally here's the `my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
symbolic-links=0

skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 512M
max_allowed_packet = 128M
table_open_cache = 1024
sort_buffer_size = 8M
read_buffer_size = 8M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 256M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 128M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size= 512M
thread_concurrency = 32


#innodb_use_native_aio = 0
innodb_file_per_table

max_connections=500
max_user_connections=250
wait_timeout=5
interactive_timeout=50
long_query_time=10

#slow_query_log=1
#slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysql-slow-queries.log


[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

The website is working, well okay because caching is enabled (page cache), I turned off the caching for a while on heavy load and there was error 500.

Also here's the memory usage:

```
#free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:              7           2           2           0           3           4
Swap:             0           0           0
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Is there any particular problem that you want to fix? Your server semms to be working ok. In order to know what to optimise, you need to find out where the bottleneck is, if any. Fix that, then find the next bottleneck. Rinse, repeat. If you don't know how to fix a particular bottleneck you may find it easier to get help on serverfault.com. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
pm.max_children -- decrease the value unless you expect lots of really small pages

query_cache_size= 512M -- Inefficient.  No more than 50M

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G  -- see below
```

You really should be using InnoDB, not MyISAM.

If 10K hits/day leads to 80K database hits/day, that is only 1/second, which is trivial.